# Windows 7 clients perform chdsk on every boot

Tags: windows, windows-7, hard-drive

since last microsoft patch tuesday 70% of windows 7 client in my network (active directory  domain) ask to perform a checkdisk on every boot.

**What i have already tried:**

- Let the client do the check disk on boot
- Schedule a check disk from windows 7 GUI with error correction at the next restart
- Check registry for correct autocheck value on startup ( http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/56685-check-disk-reset.html )
- Used the command "chkntfs /x c:" to remove scheduled checkdisk (was not scheduled)
- I check the HDs health with several tools and they are fine

However at every boot the windows 7 clients still ask to perform a chdsk. How can i solve it? Is there a solution that can be exectued remotely?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KB 2823324 has a bug that causes some win7 machines to BSOD and others to launch chkdsk at every reboot. It seems to be more specifically linked linked to Kaspersky AV (although I've heard of issues with machines running NOD32)

See this from Kaspersky:

http://support.kaspersky.com/9750

Comment: We use KAV - Kaspersky Endpoint security 8.x - I'll try to remove the update and i'll keep you posted!

Comment: Removing the update, schedule a full checkdisk will fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Stephane will end up taking you to a page where Microsoft has several solutions.  One of them is to download an ISO to burn to disk so you can boot from it and remove this patch.  It doesn't seem to work and the system still wants to checkdisk.  Once you boot back into windows you can type this from a command prompt:

chkntfs /X c:

And it'll remove the dirty flag from the drive and you should be okay afterward.  I think based on what I've seen so far that the patch removal AND removing the flag with chkntfs is required to get the machine to boot and not ask for a chkdsk every time.